# PUN2: Client often disconnected (client timeout) when enters the game scene on WebGL

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, webgl, photon

I made multiplayer fighting game using PUN2 (Photon Unity Networking) and it works fine on Standalone platform.

But when I build into WebGL and test it online, lobby is working fine, but clients enter the main game scene, they instantiate their 3d GameObjects at the first time, and suddenly get disconnected and I can't control the player.

I have tried many ways including KeepAliveInBackend, Rejoin, ReconnectAndRejoin factors but still happens the same issue. (Console log: Client Timeout)